# How to flash a message using Laravel 5 Authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I  want to flash a message when someone logs in using Laravel's default authentication driver. I know I could change **AuthenticatesUsers.php** and **RegistersUsers.php** but it won't push to git.

Is there any way to do this in the AuthController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your not content with how Laravel handles authentication you can very easily create a login controller with your own methods.

## Custom Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        // Load login view
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only('email', 'password')))
        {
            // Login is successful redirect user to wherever
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        
        // Login unsuccessful redirect back to form with errors
        return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with( 'error', trans('account.incorrect_credentials'));
    }   
}
```

The above is a bare bones example, you'll want to add in validation, your flash messages etc.

## Routes

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth','middleware' => 'guest'], function()
{
    Route::get('login', array(
        'as'      => 'login',
        'uses'    => 'LoginController@getLogin'
    ));
    
    Route::post('login', array(
        'as'      => 'login.post',
        'uses'    => 'LoginController@postLogin'
    ));
}
```

You may need to change the view files so the forms post to the correct routes.